# Search Text/Phrase in the Web Browser control in Vb.net

Tags: scrollbar, webbrowser-control, windows, htmltext, text-search

I am using Web Browser control to display some HTML Text in my windows application. Now i want a functionality that can be search text or phrase within the HTML text.

So can anyone help me to find out how to do this?  and if there is scroll bar on the control 
means text is too long and searched text not display because of scroll bar then after search text/phrase, focus should come on the searched text/phrase and scroll should go down accordingly.

And also i want to search in any case like if user select word "take" and then click on search ,it will search the exact word/phrase from the control. I do not want case sensitive search. If user enter "take" then it should search "Take" or "TAKE" or "take" in any case. So i do not want case sensitive search as well.

Please help me out to solve the problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN: [Finding Text in the Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).